# Triggering Elementor pop-up with php

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

My product single page template have a custom code to fire up a sizes chart image at the moment:

it is placed in single page php file

```
<a href="<?php echo get_theme_file_uri('assets/images/size-table.png') ?>" class="sizes-table-link">Size Chart</a>
```

I would like that instead of opening this certain image, it will trigger a premade elementor popup that i set earlier that its id is "8175"

Any tips?
Thanks

Comment: Your question is very unclear -- Can you elaborate, and add details?  What have you tried?  What is the issue with what you've tried?  What is your expected result?

Comment: I edit my post a little bit, thanks.

Comment: Does this help?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63481717/how-do-you-trigger-elementor-popup-via-code