# jQuery.Deferred exception: $ is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, elementor

I'm facing a strange issue with jQuery. I've created a custom snippet of code in elementor custom code and I'm loading it at the end of the body. I'm trying to [open a popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63481717/how-do-you-trigger-elementor-popup-via-code) from an accordion when an anchor tag is clicked but I'm getting these errors in the console

> Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

> jquery.min.js?ver=3.7.1:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: $ is not a function TypeError: $ is not a function`

this is the snippet of code

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('#ipopup').on('click', function(){
            window.elementorProFrontend.modules.popup.showPopup({ id: 16625 });
    });
});
</script>
```

I have not used jQuery for a long time, how I can fix this problem?

Comment: I think it is better to use jQuery instead of $.
please change $('#ipopup').on('click') into jQuery('#ipopup').on('click').
try it and inform me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Use $ inside the function scope as an alias for jQuery
    $('#ipopup').on('click', function() {
        window.elementorProFrontend.modules.popup.showPopup({ id: 16625});
    });
});
</script>
```

Pass **jQuery** object as a parameter `($)` to the `document.ready` function, allowing you to use `$` as an alias for jQuery within the scope of this function.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there might be a conflict or issue with the jQuery library.
Ensure that jQuery is included before your script, and make sure there are no other scripts that might be overwriting the `$` variable.
You can use the `jQuery` keyword instead of the `$` shorthand to avoid conflicts:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#ipopup').on('click', function(){
        window.elementorProFrontend.modules.popup.showPopup({ id: 16625 });
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If in a page Some where jQuery.noConflict() is called on the jQuery file it includes , which means $ doesn't work, but jQuery does.

**Pass $ into the function and add "jQuery" as a main function**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

});
</script>
```